# Bootstrap v4 beta scrollspy triggering too late

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I'm trying to create a demo of Bootstrap 4 beta `scrollspy.js` with minimal styling. The navigation scrolls to the correct location, though it seems like the position where the navigation active state updates is too low. The trigger point seems right below the titles instead of right above.

Have I overlooked something in the implementation? https://codepen.io/DannyJoris/pen/ZJwdbv

Comment: You need to compensate for the height of the fixed nav.

Comment: @Stuart the nav isn't fixed position though - they're not positioned on top of each other.

Comment: @Stuart oh wait you may be onto something, this works correctly: https://codepen.io/DannyJoris/pen/dzaxyG

Comment: You're right that the offset to the window top seems to influence it: https://codepen.io/DannyJoris/pen/BdMXym Also when clicking the navigation the window position _and_ the div scroll position seem to update. Seems odd.

Comment: It's not odd, the calculations are done from the top of the window.